# How to add custom css code to a standalone HTML file generated by python Bokeh, save()?

Tags: python, css, bokeh

I'm creating portable HTML files that visualize some data using python bokeh. I use some buttons (Toggle widget) to show/hide groups of plot elements (lines, circles etc.).
The problem is that there are only 4 colors available for the buttons and it's really hard to distinct between active and inactive buttons.

I decided to edit bokeh css class or add my own, dynamically.
The Toggle class has an option to use bokeh built-in css classes:

```
button = Toggle(label="Button 1", button_type="primary", css_classes=['some_class'])
```

But I can't find a way to inject the css class to the output HTML.
There is a `bokeh.resources` class that has some interesting attributes like `js_raw, css_raw` but I could not modify them:

```
from bokeh.resources import Resources
my_css_class = """
.some_class {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
} 
"""
res = Resources(js_raw="<style>{}</style".format(my_css_class))
#or
res = Resources(css_raw=my_css_class)
#or
setattr(res, 'css_raw', my_css_class)
```

Did not work:(
Returned: "AttributeError: can't set attribute"

Full code:

```
from bokeh.models.widgets import Toggle
from bokeh.io import save
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file
from bokeh.models import CustomJS
from bokeh.layouts import Column
from bokeh.resources import Resources


output_file('a.html')

N_lines = 10
x = range(3) 
fig = figure() 

# adding custom CSS class - if the button does not appear - it works:)
my_css_class = """
.some_class {
  display:none;
} 
"""
res = Resources(mode='inline', version=None, root_dir=None, minified=False, log_level='info', root_url=None, path_versioner=None, components=None)
# !!!!!!!!! line below does not add the class, toggle button still appears
res.css_raw.append(my_css_class)

# !!!!!!!!!!!!!! line below produces the error:
setattr(res, 'css_raw', my_css_class)
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
# <ipython-input-119-f642d1ca6dc6> in <module>
#      24 
#      25 # !!!!!!!!!!!!!! line below produces the error:
# ---> 26 setattr(res, 'css_raw', my_css_class)
#      27 # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#      28 # AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
#
# AttributeError: can't set attribute


callback_code = """
    active = cb_obj.active;
"""
args = [] 

for i in range(N_lines): 

    glyph = fig.line(
        x=x, 
        y=[random() for j in x], 
        color=choice(Category20_20), 
        legend=str(i)
    ) 
    args += [('line{}'.format(str(i)), glyph)]
    callback_code += "line{}.visible = active;".format(str(i))


toggle = Toggle(label="Hide All", button_type="success", active=True, css_classes=['some_class'])
toggle.callback = CustomJS(
    args={key:value for key,value in args},
    code=callback_code
)
fig.legend.click_policy='hide'

children = [fig, toggle]
col = Column(children=children)

save(col, resources=res)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `res = Resources()` `res.js_raw.append('text')` `res.css_raw.append('text')` `save(..., resources=res)` ?

Comment: You can edit the html file after it has been saved with your own <style type="text/css"><css> block in the head

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I ended up editing HTML file's  tag after the file creation.
(yes this is ugly, but it worked:))
Now you definitely can distinct between pressed(active) and un-pressed(inactive) buttons.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# need to defile paths to HTML files: FILE_IN and FILE_OUT

with open(FILE_IN,'r') as file_in:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(file_in.read())


old_style_primary = ".bk-root .bk-btn-primary.bk-active{background-color:#3276b1;border-color:#285e8e}"
new_style_primary = ".bk-root .bk-btn-primary.bk-active{background-color:#3276b1;border-color:#000000; border-width: 2px;}"

old_style_success = ".bk-root .bk-btn-success.bk-active{background-color:#47a447;border-color:#398439}"
new_style_success = ".bk-root .bk-btn-success.bk-active{background-color:#47a447;border-color:#000000; border-width: 2px;}"

old_style_warning = ".bk-root .bk-btn-warning.bk-active{background-color:#ed9c28;border-color:#d58512}"
new_style_warning = ".bk-root .bk-btn-warning.bk-active{background-color:#ed9c28;border-color:#000000; border-width: 2px;}"

old_style_danger = ".bk-root .bk-btn-danger.bk-active{background-color:#d2322d;border-color:#ac2925}"
new_style_danger = ".bk-root .bk-btn-danger.bk-active{background-color:#d2322d;border-color:#000000; border-width: 2px;}"

styles = soup.findAll('style')

style_string = str(styles[0]).replace("</style>","").replace("<style>","")
style_string = style_string.replace(old_style_primary, new_style_primary).replace(old_style_success, new_style_success).replace(old_style_warning, new_style_warning).replace(old_style_danger, new_style_danger)

styles[0].clear()
styles[0].insert(0, style_string)

with open(FILE_OUT,'w') as file_out:
    file_out.write(str(soup))
```

The `some_class` from using `css_classes=['some_class']`is applied on a highter-level div but inner-level classes override its properties, so that was not applicable in my case.